# Flutter `CMake Generate step failed. Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.`

Tags: flutter, flutter-build, flutter-windows

When I run flutter run -d windows I am getting below error. ```
PS C:\Users\meera\salesman>  flutter run -d windows
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Error:
Error evaluating generator expression:

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:saleman>
```

No target "saleman"

CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
Building Windows application...
Exception: Unable to generate build files``` I am was expecting it build windows app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue shortly after renaming my project and updating flutter, not exactly sure which one caused the issue.

I solved it by completely deleting my build folder in the project root, and letting flutter regenerate all the files. CMake was happy after that.

Comment: You made my CMake happy as well. Thanks.